# Spark [1.5] write dataframe as parquet to HDFS time increases linearly with time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on Spark 1.5 and I have a list of dataframes that I iterate over on the driver and then union 10 Dataframes using `grouped(10)` on df's list and then write the union dataframe as parquet in HDFS.

```
dfsList.toList.grouped(10).toList.zipWithIndex.par.map {
    case(f,count) => {
      f.reduce(_ unionAll _).where($"sstp".isNotNull).write.partitionBy("sstp").parquet(s"$parquetPath/${startIndex}_${count}")
  }
}
```

Now I could see that the [time to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRL89.png)

Time taken to write increases from 0.2 sec in the beginning to almost 7 minutes by 47th job, I am unable to find out the reason for this.

Please help/provide any hints or solutions to understand and fix this.

EDIT - Here is how the df.explain looks like for  a union before write.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Union
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606075)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606074,sstp#1606075,hdfspath#1606076]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606090)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606089,sstp#1606090,hdfspath#1606091]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606108)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606107,sstp#1606108,hdfspath#1606109]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606123)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606122,sstp#1606123,hdfspath#1606124]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606135)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606134,sstp#1606135,hdfspath#1606136]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606153)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606152,sstp#1606153,hdfspath#1606154]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606171)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606170,sstp#1606171,hdfspath#1606172]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606189)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606188,sstp#1606189,hdfspath#1606190]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606195)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606194,sstp#1606195,hdfspath#1606196]
 Filter isnotnull(sstp#1606198)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[sno#1606197,sstp#1606198,hdfspath#1606199]
```

EDIT 2 : I have also realized that at any given time, out of all the active jobs only 2 or 3 jobs seems to show any porgress [image: progress] rest all remain in sort of a waiting queue and this causes each job to take linearly increasing time.

Why is this happening? Possibly because my data isn't partitioned correctly.

Note: I have 10 executors with 4 cores per executor for this spark context.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please try to run a [DataFrame.explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) after the `where` before writing the data to the parquet files?

Comment: Can you explain why you're using still Spark 1.5? I mean, Spark 2.x was there for years, quite recently Spark 3.0 was released. Both are clearly faster in any sense given Tungsten optimization etc. - also most likely there won't be any support nor fixes from the devs for Spark 1.x

Comment: @werner I have posted the df.explain as asked.

Comment: @UninformedUser I know it really doesn't make sense but we weren't actively developing in this environment since long, it's just that we are working on data recovery now.